# How do I serve Monaco editor's loader.js and its dependencies on localhost in my react build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack, monaco-editor

I am using Monaco [Monaco Editor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@monaco-editor/react). After building and serving code on localhost, The Loader Script is loading from CDN

[image: Screenshot]

How can I include the files in the build?

Comment: Did you try this? https://www.npmjs.com/package/@monaco-editor/react#simple-usage

Comment: Yeah, i tried that and its working fine. 
My Editor is working fine but i want everything to be included in the build. Is there any way to achieve that? [Image](https://i.ibb.co/HBRpwd8/image.png)

Comment: What do you mean by that? How is everything not included if you use the linked implementation? Isn't importing the library precisely what will include everything in build.js? As opposed to using a CDN?

Comment: The [loader.js](https://i.ibb.co/hmF5z8c/image.png) file and its dependencies are loading from CDN instead of localhost. 
Currently i am serving the [build](https://i.ibb.co/8r6XBBh/image.png) on [localhost](https://i.ibb.co/fYCKvpM/image.png).

I want every resource to be loaded from localhost, no external request (no CDN).

Comment: This: https://github.com/suren-atoyan/monaco-loader/blob/master/src/config/index.js is used by https://github.com/suren-atoyan/monaco-loader/ to add a <script> tag to the document. Turning that off will probably require forking the module and changing it.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisG, this is very helpful.
For the loader.js's dependencies i should save them locally and then reference them in the module, right?

Comment: Did you find a solution for hosting the resources on your webserver? I have the exact same problem.

Answer (score 1):

[use monaco-editor as an npm package](https://github.com/suren-atoyan/monaco-react#use-monaco-editor-as-an-npm-package)

Starting from version v4.4.0 it's possible to use monaco-editor as an npm package; import it from node_modules and include monaco sources into your bundle (instead of using CDN). To make it work you can do the following:

```
import { loader } from "@monaco-editor/react";
import * as monaco from "monaco-editor";
loader.config({ monaco });
```

Comment: this works, but my console gets some ChunkLoadErrors as consequence. Is there a way to compile it all to my main bundle file? Thank you